# How do I resample an in-memory audio stream (byte[]) with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to resample audio byte array from 8Khz to 48Khz. The audio stream is obtained as a `byte[]` from a network socket.

Reading [Mark Heath's Blog about resampling using NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.ae/2014/05/how-to-resample-audio-with-naudio.html), I came across the following code

```
int outRate = 16000; 
var inFile = @"test.mp3"; 
var outFile = @"test resampled WDL.wav"; 
using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(inFile)) 
{ 
    var resampler = new WdlResamplingSampleProvider(reader, outRate); 
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(outFile, resampler); 
}
```

But this code acts on a file stream (`AudioFileReader`) rather than in memory data (`byte[]`). How could I modify this code to up-sample my byte array?

**Edit:** Basically I want to up-sample the 8 KHz data obtained from a network peer to 48 KHz and play using WASAPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input to the resampler could be a `BufferedWaveProvider` or a `RawSourceWaveStream`. You can't use CreateWaveFile16 to resample in real-time though. You'd need to read only the amount of audio you expect to be available and write it to the WAV file.

Comment: WdlResamplingSampleProvider takes an object which implements ISampleProvider, but BufferedWaveProvider and RawSourceWaveStream both implements IWaveProvider. Does this mean I need to implement custom BufferedWaveProvider which implements ISampleProvider or is there any other work around?

Comment: And I don't need to write to a wav file. Rather, I want to play the upsampled audio data using WASAPI. I think the way I formed the question confused you. Hence updating the question

Comment: @Fadi there's a .ToSampleProvider extension method you can use. But if you simply want to play the upsampled data with WASAPI then simply pass a BufferedWaveProvider into WasapiOut since I've put a resampler in WasapiOut.